# How to Use Absolute Pricing for Custom Options in Magento 2 programatically

Tags: magento2, price, custom-options

My problem is to set custom option price as product price while adding to cart. Usually in Magento custom option price will add to the product price but I want to assign custom option price as product price.

For example product price is 10 and custom option price is 20. When product is added, it will assume total price as 10+20 = 30. But I want product price to be 20 only.

I need a suggestion, can we keep product price as "0" so that product price will become the custom option price when added? Please let me know if there is any better approach or it is already answered somewhere.

Note: Removed answer from question and posted it as answer

Comment: if anyone find this useful please accept and vote it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Is this something similar? https://magecomp.com/magento-2-custom-options-absolute-price.html

Comment: "Magento 2 Custom Options Absolute Price by MageComp allows adding absolute price to override base price. " My code only does this part but magecomp module has many other features

Comment: Can you please up vote if it helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution you can apply. It will work even if you have multiple custom options for a product.

create events.xml in the folder 'Namespace/Module/etc/frontend' and use the event 'checkout_cart_product_add_after'

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="customproductprice" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\CustomProductPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create CustomProductPrice.php in Observer folder.

```
<?php
    namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

    class CustomProductPrice implements ObserverInterface
    {
        protected $_objectManager;
        public function __construct(
                \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
            ) {
                $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
            }
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
            $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
            $product=$observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
            $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
            $_customOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($product); 
            $totalPrice = 0;
            foreach ($_customOptions['options'] as $key => $value) {
                $customOptions = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);
                foreach ($customOptions as $o) {
                    $values = $o->getValues();
                    foreach ($values as $v) {
                        if ($value['option_value'] == $v->getOptionTypeId()) {
                            $totalPrice += $v->getprice(); /* get price of custom option*/
                        }
                     }
                }
            }
            $item->setCustomPrice($totalPrice);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($totalPrice);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: will it work for my requirement. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287934/magento-2-apply-custom-pricing

Comment: it is working fine on the cart page but how can i display same price on change custom option on the product detail page?