# Magento 2: Override Product description and cart functionality

Tags: magento2.3, custom, addtocart

Want to change price-option calculation on the custom option.

> For eg: If customer selects cotton as material, width and height

- Cotton is 10$
- Width : 12
- Height :20
- Base Price : 75$

Current Calculation : 75+10+1+2 (Base price+Cotton +width **price**+height **price**)

> But i want  75*10*12*20 (Base price * Cotton * width * height )

Can anybody help me?

[How to Use Absolute Pricing for Custom Options in Magento 2 programatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204708/how-to-use-absolute-pricing-for-custom-options-in-magento-2-programatically)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the default functionality of Magento 1 or Magento 2. A complete answer to your question would require an entire module to be coded from scratch. However, there are 3rd party modules that do exactly what you want and more.

Some good links to check out are:

https://marketplace.magento.com/

https://www.magearray.com/formula-pricing-mathematical-formula-based-custom-pricing-extension-for-magento-2.html

https://www.micosolutions.com/magento-2-custom-math-pricing

Comment: thx for ur comment. I know its not possible. But i want to override the default functionality where it adds to multiply